# My 2x2 has a twisted corner

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

So my 2x2 corner is twisted. Anyone know how to fix it without breaking the cube? The cube is the MoYu RS2M.

Answer (score 3):

Disassembly is required, twisting a single corner by normal manipulations is geometrically impossible.

There should be a screw in the centre of one of the faces. undo that.

Answer (score 0):

You can twist it back. Depending on tension, you can do this by simply gripping the corner and turning it, with a slight pull away from the center. But there is no sequence of face turns that will twist a single corner.

Comment: Unless it's the one square that won't twist! If that's the one that's off, then you'd need to do an alg to fix 2 corners so the original twisted corner is solved and a different one is twisted, and twist that one.

Answer (score 0):

If you loosen the tension using a screwdriver(twist the screw counterclockwise), you can gently twist the piece, make sure it is not the anchor piece though, if you forcibly twist the anchor piece, the cube will break, if it seems that it cannot twist, twist another corner to make to cube solvable. And you can undo the loosening later.